# dataGridView1_CellValueChanged not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagrid

I know there are hundreds of questions about this and believe me, i've read them all but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a win form with a datagrid that i am populating like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=testuser12;" +
                                   "password=Reporting11#;Data Source=SERVER;" +
                                   "Initial Catalog=Partner_database; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[Test_table]", con);

        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        sda.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
        sda.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        set.Clear();

        cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda); // using this to update the database
        sda.Fill(set,"cucu");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = set;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "cucu";
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;//line added after solution given
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;//line added after solution given

    }
```

Then i am trying to catch the CellValueChange event to run something like:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Age") // deleted this line after solution was given
        //if (e.ColumnIndex > -1) // i have also tried with this one but does not work
        {

            MessageBox.Show("It works!");
        }
    }
```

Cannot seem to make it work. I am modifying the cell and also change the focus to another cell to try and trigger the event. I'm going crazy. What am i missing?

Thank you.
Danut

EDIT 1: based on replies so far.

I tried deleting the IF clause in the CellValueChanged event just to test if the event is working. It did not trigger.

I tried with CellEndEdit event, still did not trigger.

Is there anything i need to do when initializing the Grid? Or something to do to make the event trigger?

EDIT 2:

Now the event is triggered with this sollution: "You need to set up the event handler on the DataGridView. Go you the events panel in the properties tab and double click on the required event type, this will create and wire up you event handler... Alternatively you can do this manually by writing: dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;"

But it gets triggered when the grid is populated with data and i get the box many times.

EDIT 3: SOLUTION GIVEN - solved

I have added 2 lines of code(see them in my code above). I have also reset the event in the datagrid properties and only used those 2 lines to condition the trigger.

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: pls try `cellendedit` instead and check if its working or not?

Comment: Tried that now, still nothing. It does not trigger. (i am selecting another cell to lose focus, and selecting other object apart from the grid)

Comment: is editable set to true?

Comment: Yes, "Enable editing" is true. I am using this Datagrid to update the sql database, so it is editable.

Comment: Try to debug with **Debug->Step Into** [F11] ... you will see whether the event get fired or not! and the value of `dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name`

Comment: I stepped into and went through until i changed the value of a cell in the grid. It did not step into running the trigger dataGridView1_CellValueChanged and neither dataGridView1_CellEndEdit. Tried with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the database is updated from SQL add the following

```
dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

This should enable the `DataGridView` to accept changes.

I hope this helps.

---

This did not work. Okay so, you need to set up the event handler on the `DataGridView`. Go you the events panel in the properties tab and double click on the required event type, this will create and wire up you event handler... Alternatively you can do this manually by writing:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
```

The first ensures you do not 'stack' the handlers.

Comment: Trigger not firing. Nothing happens when i am changing cell values on that column. The MessageBox is not shown.

Comment: Take the logic out before the massage box. Don't complicate getting the event to fire. Remove the `if` statement...

Comment: Ok, i tried deleting the If clause so i only have the event and the box. Still not firing? Do i need to tell it to look for the event or something? It's like the code isn't there at all.

Comment: You need to set up the event handler on the `DataGridView`. Go you the events panel in the properties tab and double click on the required event type, this will create and wire up you event handler... Alternatively you can do this manually by writing: `dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;`...

Comment: Wow. I did that and now it works. But i get the textbox many times when the grid gets populated. Do i need to use CellEditEnd or some other event to trigger it only when i go to a cell and change it's value?

Comment: No, if you wire the event hanlder up manually, because it is a delegate, it will queue successive additions via `+=`. So, every tie you add an event handler manually that should only every be fired once per call, first do `dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;` then `dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;`.

Comment: Great, i have cleared the even from the datagrid properties and added the 2 line you gave me. Now it work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if( dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.ToLower().Trim().Equals("age") )
```

Comment: @Danut, please make sure `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged` event alone is working first

Comment: How do i check that? I wanted to check if it's working by showing the box or not.

Comment: yes, don't test the `if` condition, just do `MessageBox.Show` first